# How to update angular application if new dependency is added in package.json and use it in component file?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I am trying to use one new dependency in the package.json file and trying to import in the component file before importing I am trying to install or update the dependency using **npm** but I am not able to import after adding a new dependency in package.json

Please find the existing package.json file content currently using version angular 6

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
```

After adding new content

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    **"@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.13",**
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    **"@angular/material": "6.0.3",**
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
```

I have tried with using

```
npm install
npm install -g @angular/material
npm install -g @angular/material latest
```

but no use it says updated but in the application, I am not able to import in the component file.

Can anyone suggest me any solution how to update new dependency if added in package.json and use it the component code to import the new dependency like angular material?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-2-configure-animations

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines from your **package.json** file:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
**"@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.16",**
**"@angular/material": "6.0.1",**
```

Then, run this command to install Angular material packages:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

After that you can import Angular material components like that:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material
```

Don't forget to add each component in the NgModule part:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use -g flag, with -g you are installing global packages - guess it's not what you want.